# Expresso store with a Pay Trace gateway?

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

We built site with Expresso store - client came back with a Pay Trace gateway. Anyone connected these? Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Expresso's [payment gateway docs](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/payment_gateways.html) (As of Feb. 1), you won't see any Pay Trace payment gateway.

Although, Expresso payment processing is based on Omnipay. And if you try to visit their [docs](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay), you'll see that they now support Pay Trace gateway maintained by Oleg Ilyushyn.

Maybe Expresso's docs aren't updated? Or maybe Expresso's Omnipay build is not the latest version? I'm not really sure. But If Expresso's Omnipay doesn't support Pay Trace, you might want to use the latest Omnipay separately from Expresso.